# ImportError: cannot import name 'format_exc' Error

Tags: python, python-3.x

trying to use python3 and this library and im receiving this error `ImportError: cannot import name 'format_exc'`

tried uninstalling python3 and reinstalling, im also on Ubuntu 18

need it to run my code, the code works but python3 does not

Comment: can you provide your import statement?  I'm assuming it's something like `from traceback import format_exc`

Comment: ```from traceback import format_exc as _format_exc``` im still getting the error ```ImportError: cannot import name 'format_exc'```

Comment: try `import traceback` by itself and then `dir(traceback)`. Make sure that format_exc shows up in the list that is returned by dir.

Comment: ```import traceback``` gives me ```AttributeError: module 're' has no attribute 'IGNORECASE'``` and ```dir(traceback)``` gives me ```NameError: name 'traceback' is not defined```

Comment: My guess is that your file is named re.py or maybe there is a re.py in your working directory (I'm running into some odd behavior over here when I am executing test scripts named re.py or adjacent to a re.py) and you are getting a weird conflict with the `re` that is part of the standard library.  Renamed your file and/or move it into a folder by itself see if you still get the error

Comment: i just searched my PC for the re.py and couldn't find anything

Comment: but instead i find ```core.py```

Comment: what are your other imports, where are you executing the script from, what is your scripts name, are there any other files in the directory your script is in?

Comment: its on my Desktop directory, ill try making a folder with nothing in it

Comment: i somehow fixed it with following this, https://askubuntu.com/a/981079/991511 and moved the program, thank you for the help.

Comment: @fortnite50 so what was prolem there I am having Error 
ImportError: cannot import name 'format_exc' and  I am using Python 3.5.3
what should I do ?

Comment: @Sara uninstall python3 and re-install.

Comment: @fortnite50 I had a file token.py in my directory, I renamed it and everything was ok, thanks tho !

Comment: wow. @Sara, your solution worked for me.

Answer (score 4):

Check your filenames, for example, if you have a `token.py` file in your project, rename it. Its just a conflict with the filename and some libs as *Alex Jadczak* and *Sara* pointed out.